# Converting time-series results to dates

Tags: r, forecasting, tidyverse

I use `fpp2` for forecasting. My workflow involves importing data, converting to a time series, then forecasting.

One pain-point is that after forecasting I am left with data that is an extension of my current data, but no longer retains the same `date` column.

For example, if I am working with weeks then my dates look something like the following:

```
>wks
date         wk  y
2016-01-04   1   2500
2016-01-11   2   2530
2016-01-18   3   2600
```

I then perform some forecast with, say:

```
ts(wks$y, start = 2016, freq = 52) %>%
stl(t.window=25, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE) %>%
forecast(method="naive", h = 20, level = 50) %>% 
broom::tidy() %>% 
rownames_to_column() %>% 
janitor::clean_names()
```

This gives something like

```
rowname    point_forecast   lo_50   hi_50
2016.058     some_double     ...     ...
2016.077     some_double     ...     ...
2016.096     some_double     ...     ...
```

In an ideal situation I would want to be more `tidy`. The  `tidy` output may look something like the following:

```
date           value          lo_50   hi_50      type
2016-01-04     2500             na     na       past
2016-01-11     2530             na     na       past
2016-01-18     2600             na     na       past
2016-01-25     some_double     ...     ...      forecast
2016-02-01     some_double     ...     ...      forecast
2016-02-08     some_double     ...     ...      forecast
```

Note that

1. The `rownames` are now `date`s that continue on the same timeline as the given data.
2. The past data and the forecast data are row bound
3. The `values` for both the `past` data and `forecast` data are in the same column. This makes it easy to plot with `ggplot2`

I am guessing that I am not the only person working in forecasting that also enjoys using the `tidyverse`. How do you convert forecasting outputs to something tidy and similar to what I have described above?

## EDIT

I wanted to add that I provided an example of weeks, but if anyone had a method or tool that generalized the same idea to days that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through some tools and posts I found this [business-science](http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2017/07/09/sweep-0-1-0.html) post answering all of my questions and giving me the exact results I was looking for.

The key functions being `tk_ts` which indexes the time-series and `sw_sweep(rename_index = "date")` which takes forecast data and returns the date index.

More info about which `tidiers` to use for different forecasts (ets, arima, stl, etc.) can be found [here](https://business-science.github.io/sweep/).

### Edit

It seems I may have spoke too soon. I am having some issues with retrieving dates from weekly level forecasts, but maybe this is due to my inexperience with the package.

Comment: FYI - the business-science folks are pretty active on twitter. If you determine a good method, please try and post a follow-up complete answer.